# Jetpack Compose Icon's color is switched in real device

Tags: icons, android-jetpack-compose

Both devices are in dark mode and for some reason the icons in my real device are black in dark mode and all white in light mode.

if I set the color to be white, they stay black in dark mode and if I set the color to be black they stay white in light mode.

Only if I set the color to  another color other than plain white or black(for example: Red) the color is applied to the icon.

[image: This is the real device]

This is the emulator
[image: This is the emulator]

This is the real device (Mi 9T Pro)

**Edit 1:**

It is working as expected on emulator but not on the real device

**Implementation**

```
BottomNavigationItem(
        icon = {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(
                    id = screen.icon
                ),
                contentDescription = screen.title,
            )
        },
        selectedContentColor = Color.White,
        unselectedContentColor = Color.White.copy(alpha = .3f)
        ...
    )
```

The result from this code as explain above sets the icons color to white in dark mode and black for light mode in the emulator but it is reversed in the real device, so black for dark mode and white for light mode.

Comment: Is it working as expected on the emulator?

Comment: Please add the code you're using to display the icon and to change its color.

Comment: @Abhimanyu yes it is